# Random template not found with Freemarker

Tags: templates, freemarker

I'm using FreeMarker with a Play 2.3.8 app.
When I execute my tests, sometimes I get the following error :

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Template "MyTemplate.tpl"
>   not found. The quoted name was interpreted by this template loader:
>   ClassTemplateLoader(baseClass=com.project.TemplateEngineConfigurer,
>   packagePath="templates/").

`MyTemplate.tpl` is in `com.project.templates` package and I'm using the following configuration :

```
    Configuration config = new Configuration(Configuration.getVersion());
    config.setClassForTemplateLoading(getClass(), "templates");
    config.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    config.setCacheStorage(new MruCacheStorage(20, 250));
    return config;
```

I can't understand why I have randomly, file not found exception... Is it an Eclipse problem ? A cache problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: Strange. Can you add and log the result of `TemplateEngineConfigurer.class.getResource(templatePath)` after such an error occurs, while the `freemarker.cache` log category is set to debug log level?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but note that here you negate what the constructor argument exists for: `new Configuration(Configuration.getVersion())`:

Comment: Actually I fixed the problem. It was a problem of Play who was not copying templates in target directory.